# ngx-toaster is notifying in the wrong place of the screen by default

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular10, toastr

This is the problem
[image: it's presenting the notification by default up above, maybe it's getting affected by CSS properties ??]
it's presenting the notification by default up above, maybe it's getting affected by CSS properties ??

when I configure the place in the import of the module like this :

```
imports: [
  ...
  ...,
  ToastrModule.forRoot(
   positionClass: 'toastr-bottom-right'
  )
]
```

well when I did this, it puts the notification in the up-left corner, in addition to that is not showing any message as you can see in the screenshot it's only a red (error) toastr notification but empty, even though I did pass it a message to notify when a user is not login correctly.

Here is my AppModule:
[image]

here is my component code

```
export class NavComponent  {

  ...
  ...
  ...
  model: any = {};
  loggedIn: boolean;

  constructor(
    private accountService: AccountService, 
    private router: Router,
    private toastr: ToastrService
    ) { }
  ...
  ...
  login(){
      this.accountService.login(this.model).subscribe(response => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/agents');
      }, errorResponse => {
        console.log(errorResponse);
        this.toastr.error(errorResponse.eror);
      });
  }
```

I'm using Angular 10.

Comment: Check spelling of bottom in your positionClass parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is silly, but the answer is I was misspelling the configuration I put:

```
positionClass: "toastr-bottom-right"
```

but it was "toast-bottom-right" without the "r"

```
positionClass: "toast-bottom-right"
```

Comment: I have the same issue with correct spelling positionClass: "toast-bottom-right" but the bug is still there for me

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of bottom here.

```
ToastrModule.forRoot({
    timeOut: 10000,
    positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',
  }),
```

You can ignore `timeOut` here.

Comment: The spelling mistake was only here, and without any configuration it's in a wrong position by default

Answer (score 0):

Or consider another provider and generate toast notification snippet directly there, playground:

https://costlydeveloper.github.io/ngx-awesome-popup/#/playground/toast-generator

**Works for Angular 9+**